# How to consume, read and unzip a third party API response in ASP.Net MVC application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to consume a third party API whose URL looks like this:

```
https://api.crowdin.com/api/project/{PROJECT_NAME}/download/all.zip?key={MY_KEY}
```

This api returns a zip file as "all.zip" as response.

When I go to browser and make this request I get a all.zip file downloaded. Now I want to write C# code to get this result. Below is my attempt:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.crowdin.com/");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/project/{MY_PROJECT}/download/all.zip?key={MY_KEY}");
           // WHAT TO WRITE HERE
            return View();
        }
```

Question 1: I got the successful response and content type is `application/zip`, but now I don't know how to read this response.

Question 2: I want the response to unzipped and saved to a folder.

P.S: The response *.zip* file is a collection of *.resx File.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly from memory so I haven't tested the code.  It should get you pretty close to what you're looking for:

Saving the response to file:

```
var response = httpClient.GetAsync("api/project/{MY_PROJECT}/download/all.zip?key={MY_KEY}");
using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
using (var fs = new FileStream(filename) {
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
}
```

Unzipping the file (you could also do this in memory)

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(filename, extractPath);
```

Comment: What do I need to put inplace of `filename`?

Comment: The file name... where you want to save the file.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!